# How to resolve booting problem in my system(14.04)?

Tags: system-installation

I have installed version 14.04 64bit onto a new hard drive in my PC.

It's not booting from the hard drive. I also tried to install the 32bit version over it but when it gets to the install option screen it closes to a blank screen.

I am using AMD 690G processor.

What could be wrong?

Comment: Is this "new hard drive" a second hard-drive or do you mean that you have replaced your main hard-drive by a new one ? Could you give us more info about your hardware setup ?

Answer (score 0):

Since it's a new hard drive, you might need to set the correct boot device order in your BIOS. Make sure your new hard drive comes before any other hard drives.

Answer (score 0):

yes he is right
Since it's a new hard drive, you might need to set the correct boot device order in your BIOS. Make sure your new hard drive comes before any other hard drives.